# How To Filter On Bcc Info

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-office-2010, rules

I've created a rule that checks for messages sent to a distribution list, but I'm finding that the rules is missing messages in a thread where the sender moves the DL address to BCC. Basically, I want to check if my name is not on the To: or CC: fields. How can I write a rule that takes this into account?

Answer (score 2):

You have to create the following rule:

Apply this rule after the message arrives
 move it to the BULK folder
 except if my name is in the To or Cc box

This will move any mail not specifically sent to you to the BULK folder.

Note that if someone sends you a personal email but uses the BCC field, this rule will fire as well. Note also that you may need to check "...and stop processing rules"  to *all* your *other* rules.

Answer (score 1):

i am assuming you mean to have outlook check emails when received for your name on the **TO** or the **CC** and you want to add the **BCC** to the filter.......

**BCC** is intended to hide from the email receiver others that have been copied on the same email. so no, you cannot check for anything in this field.

hope this helps

Comment: Yeah, but can't I filter to check if my name isn't in the To: or CC: box? I didn't see that option.