# (no-answer) Filter Outlook messages with blank To and Cc fields

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

Executives at my company typically send/broadcast messages with blank To: & Cc: fields (i.e., every address/DL is Bcc'd). I'd like to filter these messages to a specific folder.

I can't simply filter messages that don't include me or the DLs which include me for two reasons:

- I am sometimes added to DLs without notice
- DLs of DLs (of DLs (of DLs)) are in constant flux

I don't want to filter all messages from the execs, only the broadcasts.

Is there any rule or small set of rules which could accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that a broadcast message has the following conditions:

- You are not in the To: field
- You are not in the CC: field

In this case, you can simply setup a filter to move all messages to a "Broadcast" folder except for messages where your name is in the To: or CC: field. There is already an answer for this on superuser:

[How To Filter On Bcc Info](https://superuser.com/questions/185821/how-to-filter-on-bcc-info)

You will still get direct messages from execs or non-boradcast messages sent to the list.

Comment: What about messages with a DL I'm on in either field?

Comment: The distribution list should resolve to your name in the proper field while the message is being processed by the exchange server. So being a part of that distribution list essentially adds you to that field.

Comment: Alas, 'tis not so. I tested the following: `Apply this rule after the message arrives move it to the _EXEC folder except if my name is in the To or Cc box`, and it caught a test message sent only to DLs.

Answer (score 0):

We had the issue of the To field being blank suddenly with all emails in our organization. We found out we had been hacked! If you think this may be the case, sign in as admin and check for 'rules'. change your passwords ASAP and set up MFA. Better safe than sorry!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).