# How to identify recipient address when To and CC are blank?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I often receive emails with blank To and Cc columns in my Outlook.

There are 2 possibilities for me receiving the email:

1. I was Bcc'd, or
2. A mailing list (which I'm part of) was Bcc'd.

How can I pin down which of the above 2 is correct? Is there an option in Outlook that will let me show the Bcc field? I know I wouldn't know all other people who were Bcc'd, but that's anyway not what I'm looking for. Why would outlook not display this anyway?

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/436439/filter-outlook-messages-with-blank-to-and-cc-fields) is a similar question, but I'm more keen on finding out why I'm receiving the email in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only possible way is to look at message's internet headers. Some email servers save original recipient in one of the X-headers. There are no other ways. So, if you can't see anything useful in there then you have to ask the sender of the message, sorry.

For Outlook 2007, [this](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/View-e-mail-message-headers-cd039382-dc6e-4264-ac74-c048563d212c) is how you view the internet header.